# Вывод ассемблеровского кода в с++

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Добрый день.
Столкнулся с проблемой компиляции кода asm в с++.
Есть переменная asmCode - sting. А в ней, собственно, содержится код asm.
Пример кода будет в конце вопроса.
А вопрос заключается в следующем: если я вывожу, допустим, cout << asmCode; - мне выводит не скомпилированный код asm. Если я пытаюсь вывести _asm(asmCode); - мне бьёт либо

> Ошибка    C2400   синтаксическая ошибка во встроенном коде на языке ассемблера в "код операции"; обнаружено "newline".

Либо

> Ошибка    C2400   синтаксическая ошибка во встроенном коде на языке ассемблера в "код операции"; обнаружено "("

Дело в том, что код, который содержится в gencode автоматически создаётся в зависимости от содержимого определённого файла(своего рода компилятор), и просто вписать часть кода в _asm вручную не получится.
В проекте, который должен компилировать asm код включен masm.
Каким способом можно вывести результат asm кода из asmCode в консоль?
Если нужны будут какие-то коды, предоставлю(ибо, мне кажется, вопрос не нуждается в предоставлении кода(учитывая, что он состоит из 30 файлов).
Пример кода asm, содержащийся в asmCode(извиняюсь за корявость, не получилось его красивым сделать):

```
.586
.model flat, stdcall

includelib kernel32.lib
includelib libucrt.lib
includelib StatLibC.lib

ExitProcess      PROTO : DWORD

SetConsoleTitleA PROTO :DWORD

GetStdHandle     PROTO : DWORD

writei PROTO : SDWORD

writes PROTO : DWORD

strl   PROTO : DWORD

ipow   PROTO : DWORD, : DWORD

sum    PROTO : DWORD, : DWORD
.stack 4096



.data


.const

csname db 'BNI-2016', 0

Overflow db 'ERROR overflow', 0

DIV_NULL db 'ERROR DBN', 0

newline db '0',0

L0 SDWORD  5

L1 SDWORD  0

.stack 4096

.code

main PROC 

 push offset csname

 call SetConsoleTitleA

  push L0

 call writei

 jmp EXIT

EXIT_div_on_NULL:

 push offset DIV_NULL

 call writes


 push - 1

 call ExitProcess


EXIT_overflow:

 push offset Overflow

 call writes

 push - 2

 call ExitProcess

EXIT:

  push L1

 call ExitProcess

main ENDP

end main
```

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите *во время выполнения программы* **генерировать** некоторый asm-код и **выполнять** его? Или я неправильно понял?

Comment: @Harry, Правильно. Но, как я понимаю, скорее всего это - просто невозможно и для этого нужно писать какие-то дополнительные методы, в которые будет отправляться строка и нужными способами форматироваться?

Comment: Для этого вам нужен компилятор времени выполнения, который сможет скомпилировать ваш исходник, а потом соответствующая среда выполнения. Вряд ли написание такого компилятора/интерпретатора времени выполнения проще, чем решение вашей задачи иным путем... Встает множество вопросов - почему именно ассемблер, почему именно так, а не иначе. Может, ваш гвоздь можно забить не этим микроскопом? :) И еще - гляньте http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1738-6.html - там нет решения именно вашей задачи, но там могут быть идеи, которые вам пригодятся.